# Unexpected preg behaviour with angle brackets

Tags: php, regex

Why do the angle brackets in the target string negate the match text in the second example.

```
$str = '[example1](example2)';
echo preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]\((.*)\)/', '$2 $1', $str);

// output: example2 example1

$str = '[example1](<example2>)';
echo preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]\((.*)\)/', '$2 $1', $str);

// output: example1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<example2>` is parsed by the browser as a tag, so it doesn't show up. If you right-click and View Source, you'll see it right there. Similarly, if you run this through CLI, you'll see the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '[example1](<example2>)';


echo $str;
```

will produce `[example1]()` for you because the web browser assumes `<example2>` is html markup.
Same happens while **displaying** results of following. The match happens to be just fine.

```
echo preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]\((.*)\)/', '$2 $1', $str);
```